# Getting a unique pair of an array using nested loops in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am currently learning ruby and am very new to it. I usually write code in javascript but because I am entering a bootcamp next year I took it upon myself to learn as much ruby before my cohort starts. So the practice problem that I'm trying to solve is getting the indices of elements that equivalent to a certain number, in which case lets give an example 0.

I can do this with no problem for JS but I am learning how to write in Ruby.

```
//JS 
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
       if(arr[j] + arr[i] === 0){
           someVar.push([i,j]);
       }
    }
}
```

The block code above displays where I am getting each unique pair and which ever one of these pairs return a sum 0 their indices get pushed inside the result.

I am still very new with how ruby writes loops and there is a plethora of ways to do it.

```
  def two_sum(nums)
  result = []
  n = nums.length

  n.times do |i|
    n.times do |j|

      if nums[i] + nums[j] == 0
        result.push([i,j])
      end
    end
  end
  result
end
```

I've tried doing it this way but it doesn't give me the right output. I also understand that `n.times do |j|` is not the same as `for(let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)`. But I don't know how else to write this so I did something like:

```
n.times do |i|
  x = i + 1
  x.times do |j|
```

My intuition is telling me that this is not the way to write an inner loop.

Comment: What would be an input and output as example of this?

Comment: So lets say I need the indices of the elements whose sum is 3 so our array is `arr = [3,2,1,0,5]` our return should be `[[0,3],[1,2]]` because 3+0 = 3 and 2+1 = 3. It's really simple its just the darn syntax.

Comment: @ken wouldn't [1,2,0] also be a answer? or is the combinations that of only pairs?

Comment: Do you wish to return an array of pairs of numbers from a given array that sum to a given value (e.g., zero)?

Comment: The problem only wanted a pair not more than two indices.

Comment: Is it possible that there will be identical values in the array? e.g. `[1,1,2]` and if so, does it matter which index is used?

Comment: Does the order of the indices within each pair matter? In other words, in your first comment would `[[3,0],[2,1]]` be acceptable? I ask because @StefanPochmann is holding me to task :)

Comment: I don't think it does matter. If you start looking for the pair from the end of the string you would get `[[3,0],[2,1]]`. As long as the logic is sound in which case the elements of these indices equate to a certain value it should be good.

Comment: In that case my second edit produces a correct result. Feel free to select whichever answer best suits your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `select` the appropriate sums from all the pairs (combinations of 2).

```
def two_sum(nums)
  nums.combination(2).select{|pair| pair.sum == 3}
end
```

**Edit**: more details on what's going on:

As you know, we pass in an array called `nums`. If you go to the [documentation for `Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html), you'll see a method called `combination`. By the way, I *highly* recommend that you, as a newcomer to Ruby, become familiar with all the methods on `Array` (as well as `Enumerable`, which I'll explain in a bit). The `combination` method "yields all combination of elements of length n" and we will use n=2:

```
p [3,2,1,0,5].combination(2).to_a
#=> [[3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 5], [2, 1], [2, 0], [2, 5], [1, 0], [1, 5], [0, 5]]
```

Now if you omitted the `.to_a` above, you'd see that the output of `combination` is actually an `Enumerator`. And if you look carefully at [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html), you'll see under "Included Modules" it lists `Enumerable`. `Enumerable` is designed to be a "mixin", which can add methods to other classes (even your own). [Side note: In fact, if you look at the docs for `Array`, it includes `Enumerable` as well. The combination of these methods available to your Ruby arrays make them very powerful, and why I recommend learning them]. The [`select` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) takes a [block](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/blocks.html) and it will return all the elements for which the given block is true. So, we are checking every element to see if the sum is 3, for example:

```
[2,1].sum == 3
#=> true (and therefore [2,1] will be included in the output)
```

The output of `select`, and therefore the `two_sum` method, is an array of all the matches (the elements where the block was true).

**Edit 2**

It was pointed out by Stefan in the comments that the results above are returning values, not indices. One way to fix that is to add an index lookup to the results:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  nums.combination(2)
      .select{|pair| pair.sum == 3}
      .map{|pair| [nums.index(pair[0]), nums.index(pair[1])] }
end
```

Not quite as succinct, but at least it outputs indices now :)

Comment: That is way beyond what I know at the moment. I haven't even touched on classes yet alone these more advanced methods. Can you put into your own words what the 2nd line of code is doing?

Comment: I've explained it a bit, see if that helps.

Comment: This doesn't do the job. You're returning array elements, not their indices. Also, your explanation isn't right. Yes, `Array` includes `Enumerable`, but `Array` has its own `select`, doesn't use the one from `Enumerable`. But that doesn't even matter, since you're not using `select` on the array but on the `Enumerator` that you get from `combination`. And that `Enumerator` gets its `select` from including `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Ken mentions indices, but from his comments it is clear he wants the values returned (maybe the values are indices for something else).

Comment: Yes, the mention about `Enumerable` being mixed in to `Array` was really a side note, not intended to be part of the explanation of what's happening. Perhaps I should reword it to be more clear.

Comment: @MarkThomas What comments of Ken are you talking about? None I see say that. I even see one that reinforces that he wants indices.

Comment: His first comment mentions indices but his expected output are the values.

Comment: Ha! You are right. That exact output coincidentally works for the values too. I hang my head in shame :). It was very late for me when I answered :) Let's see if I can salvage it.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yeah, it's a very bad example, easy to confuse indices with values. I wrote indices-solutions already but sadly they're much less nice.

Comment: About the update: The answer isn't really the same, not even for that example. `[[0, 3], [1, 2]]` and `[[3, 0], [2, 1]]` differ. And your new code fails for example for input `[1, 1, 2]`, returning `[[0, 2], [0, 2]]` instead of `[[0, 2], [1, 2]]`.

Comment: You're a tough customer. It is returning _an_ index of each value, who's to say it's wrong? OP didn't specify what happens when two values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to resemble your JS snippet, then here's a version using the appropriate ruby loops.

```
0.upto(arr.length - 1) do |i|
  (i + 1).upto(arr.length - 1) do |j|
    if arr[i] + arr[j] == 0
      result.push([i, j])
    end
  end
end
```

But more idiomatic ruby would be that in MarkThomas' answer (or something similar).

Comment: I don't recommend writing Ruby code that resembles JS ;)

Comment: @MarkThomas: me neither! But hey, one needs a stepping stone :)